# Unwanted favicon appears in my Node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, favicon

I am brand new to using the backend of Node.js, and I am attempting to install favicons to my project using RealFaviconGenerator. I follow the directions, but the favicons do not appear either in my [development site](https://github.com/DivideBySara/codefellowsportfolio) or on my deployed site. Instead, I get an unwanted favicon!

I suspect a server call is being made somewhere to retrieve the unwanted favicon, but I can't find it. I've even put the favicons at both the root of my app and inside `OutputDir`. I've had success with RealFaviconGenerator on my Rails app, so I'm not sure why it doesn't seem to work with Node.js.

I realize that I could add a link to the `favicon.ico` file, but that would not take advantage of the RealFaviconGenerator's favicons for nearly all browsers and mobile technologies. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my current directory tree:

[image]

I also tried installing express-favicon-short-circuit middleware. No dice.

Comment: RealFaviconGenerator's author speaking. Did you check that the favicon HTML markups were correctly injected in your pages? Do you know where does this unwanted icon come from? (a stray favicon.ico in your project, maybe?)

Comment: Nope, nothing gets injected into html as far as I can tell, but then I'm not certain how to check. And no, I don't know where the unwanted favicon comes from, so I assume a server call is being made. Do you know where the server would make such a call?

Comment: The HTML markups in your `faviconData.json` should be injected in your pages. Did you run `real-favicon inject faviconData.json outputDir public/index.html` or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a favicon with your site, you add a link to the  of the index.html file:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://codefellowswebapp.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico" />
```

And you save the favicon as an .ico file at the root of your site directory.

Does RealFaviconGenerator not export a .ico file based on an uploaded image?

Comment: [RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) is  supposed to inject the html without me adding the above link directly. That way, it can add any number of favicons depending on the browser, and almost any browser will display the favicon. In other words, lots of icon files, including a .ico, file have been exported to `outputDir`, but they don't appear. Moving the icon files to the root directory doesn't help. I've used [RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) successfully on my Rails app, so I am disappointed that something is going wrong with my Node.js app.